# Cannot play sound every second?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to play an AudioSource every second only if a specific script is enabled:

```
public int wait = 1;
bool keepPlaying = true;

void Start () 
{
    StartCoroutine(SoundOut());
}

IEnumerator SoundOut()
{
    while (keepPlaying)
    {
        if (GameObject.FindWithTag ("GameObject").GetComponent<SpecificScript> ().enabled == true)
        {
            GameObject.FindWithTag ("GameObject").GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();  
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (wait);
        }
    }
}
```

This script does not play the sound every second when the specific script is enabled. What's the problem?

Comment: `return new WaitForSeconds (carwait)` what is the `carwait`?

Comment: @Valentin Sorry, my mistake. I edited the question.

Comment: But it plays anything?

Comment: this is completely wrong, Pik. Just use `InvokeRepeating` to do this.  so it's just `InvokeRepeating( "Playit", .1f, 2f );`

Comment: and then have a simple routine `private void Playit() {blah.Play();}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [PlayOneShot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html)

```
float wait = 1;
bool keepPlaying = true;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SoundOut());
}

IEnumerator SoundOut()
{
    while (keepPlaying)
    {
        if (GameObject.FindWithTag("GameObject").GetComponent<SpecificScript>().enabled == true)
        {
            AudioSource myAudioSource = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameObject").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            myAudioSource.PlayOneShot(myAudioSource.clip);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this technique, if your clip is > 1 second, they will overlap.

If you don't want that, just do myAudioSource.Stop(); before playing it again.